# node js mongo search

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

i want search for an id in a subject model, the model has an array of teachers id as follows

```
var Classroom = require('./classroom');
var Teacher = require('./teacher');
var ClassSectionSchema = new Schema({
 title : String,
 teacher_id : [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Teacher'}]

});
```

i want to search for every teacher before deleting it but if the teacher is connected in a class section i dont want to delete it, i tried the following

```
router.post('/delete',function(req,res){
var teacher_id= req.body.selected;

Class_section.findOne({teacher_id:teacher_id},function(err,subject){
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
        res.json({status:"error", message :"error occurred"});
        return;
    }else if(subject){
        res.json({status:"error", message:"teacher has class"});
        return;
    }else{
        Teacher.remove({_id:teacher_id},function(err){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                res.json({status:"error", message :"error occurred"});
                return;
            }else{
                res.json({status:"success",message: "teacher deleted"});
                return;
            }
        })
    }
})
})
```

the previous code only works if the class section has one teacher id, but if it has two teacher in the array of teacher ids the teacher gets deleted

Answer (score 0):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
var ObjectId = mongoose.Types.ObjectId();

router.post('/delete',function(req,res){
  var queryObj = {};
  if(req.body.selected){
     queryObj.teacher_id = {
        $in:[new ObjectId(req.body.selected)]
     }
}

Class_section.find(queryObj,function(err,subject){
if(err){
    console.log(err);
    res.json({status:"error", message :"error occurred"});
    return;
}else if(subject.length > 0){
    res.json({status:"error", message:"teacher has class"});
    return;
}else if(subject.length == 0){
    Teacher.remove({_id:teacher_id},function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
            res.json({status:"error", message :"error occurred"});
            return;
        }else{
            res.json({status:"success",message: "teacher deleted"});
            return;
        }
    })
}
})
})
```